# "Make money off of" vs. "make money out of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, off-of

Which one sounds correct?

> 1. I am not making any money off of this product.
> 2. I am not making any money out of this product.

If you tell me both, then how would you explain "off" here as it doesn't sound right to me since "make off" means:

> Run away; usually includes taking something or somebody along

Comment: "*Off of*" is **superfluous** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/superfluous?q=superfluous and **wordy** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wordy?q=wordy . The word *off* without *of*, is sufficient.

Comment: Providing what appear to be references for your unsupported claim, but are actually just definitions for the (perfectly ordinary) words you are using in your claim, is unhelpful. It is true that _off of_ is both superfluous and widely deprecated in the UK. It is also true that _out of_ is wordy compared to _out_, but it is that latter that is generally deprecated. This shows that the pundits' imprimatur has nothing to do with wordiness, and everything to do with arbitrariness.

Comment: I thought they were helpful. "*Off of*" does contain too many words for what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer the second one, although not because of the reason you cited.

"Make money off (of) something" is different from the phrasal verb "make off."

Both "make money out of" and "make money off" are actually right.

For me though, "make money off" may also be used to imply an unscrupulous method of generating income.

```
ex. make money off my friends, make money off the mentally ill etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like another US/UK split. Looking at Ngrams, *"make money out of"* is the traditional way of saying it, but in the U.S., *"make money off (of)"* has now overtaken *out of* in frequency. [From Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+money+out+of%2Cmake+money+off%2Cmake+money+off+of&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

[image]

In the U.K., *out of* is still [far more common.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+money+out+of%2Cmake+money+off%2Cmake+money+off+of&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3) Since it's still correct in the U.S., you should probably choose *out of* if you're deciding between them.

Since the phrasal verb *make off* does not take an object, the meaning *run away* is impossible for *"make money off"*; to use the phrasal verb with *money* as an object, you would need to say *"make off with money"*.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the second one makes impression of being too literal. Like minting coins off arcade tokens, or printing notes.
What about *making money on something*?

Answer (score 0):

*Off of* is a compound preposition common in London (and possibly elsewhere in the UK) but deprecated by purists, who strongly prefer either *from* or in some cases *off*. Said purists do not appear to have any objection to *out of*.

In your example, *out of* or *from* are idiomatic. One does hear *off* or *off of* in this use, but they are not standard.

Comment: *"Off of"* is not deprecated in the US, and *"make money off of"* is idiomatic in the US.

Comment: "*Off of*" is not common in the UK because the "*of*" is superfluous. It's considerably more common in American English.

Comment: @Tristanr: so for some reason British speakers are more prone than Americans to avoid superfluous words? And your evidence for this remarkable claim?

Comment: Colin Fine, is personal experience acceptable?

Comment: For usage and meaning, of course (though it's good if we can find a reference). For explaining the reason why we do or don't say something (your _because_), not so much.

Comment: If you think about it logically, *off of* is not necessary because it does not add any extra meaning. No more than just using the word *off*. It's just superfluous and wordy. Used just for the sake of it.

Comment: If you pay attention to Americans speaking and writing, it's noticeable how many superfluous wordings they use, especially with the word *of*.

Comment: I suspect that if you pay attention to British people speaking and writing, you'll find just as many superfluous words, though perhaps different ones. I may be wrong, though, as I haven't checked.